# A condition for a bounded $T:X^* \rightarrow Y^*$ being a dual operator

Tags: functional-analysis

So I am trying to learn some functional analsysis, but the weak star stuff really confuses me. I came across this one and am completely lost. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and let $F:X^*\rightarrow Y^*$ be a bounded linear operator. Show there is a bounded linear operator $G:Y\rightarrow X$ with $G^*=F$ if and only if $F:(X^*,wk*)\rightarrow(Y^*,wk*)$ is continuous. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Is it by any chance assumed that the Banach spaces are reflexive?

Comment: Don't need reflexivity. The question is correct.

Comment: One direction is easy. Another direction is tricky.

Comment: The "tricky" point is that every element of $(X^*, wk*)^*$ is given by an evaluation in $x\in X$, more briefly  $(X^*, wk*)^*=X$. Then $G=F^*$ does the job.